# find the difference between date and time in highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am trying to find the difference between date time, but I am getting either NaN or 0.

```
 yAxis: {  
            dateTimeLabelFormats: {
                millisecond: '%H:%M',
                second: '%H:%M:%S',
                minute: '%H:%M',
                hour: '%H:%M',
                day: '%m/%d/%Y',
                week: '%m/%d/%Y',
                month: '%m/%Y',
                year: '%Y'
            },
            units: [
                ['millisecond', [1000]],
                ['second', [60]],
                ['minute', [60]],
                ['hour', [1, 12]],
                ['day', [1]],
                ['week', [1]],
                ['month', [1]],
                ['year', null]
            ]
}
tooltip: {
           formatter: function() {
           var difference_time = Highcharts.dateFormat('%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S', 
                                this.point.startDisplay) - 
                                 Highcharts.dateFormat('%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S', 
                                 this.point.endDisplay);
            return '<b>' + this.point.status + '</b><br />' +
              this.point.startDisplay + ' <br />' +
                 this.point.endDisplay + ' <br />' +
                   difference_time;
         }
}
```

I'm difference_time value as either 0 or NaN, I am not getting how to subtract date time and get the difference in the same date-time format

Comment: If you're subtracting anything from `undefined` or by `undefined`, you will get `NaN` and if the values are same you will get 0.

Comment: Hi @user12364618, What are the values of `this.point.startDisplay` and `this.point.endDisplay`?

Comment: this.point.startDisplay - 11/12/2019 02:27:40 
this.point.endDisplay - 11/12/2019 15:17:26

Comment: and It is substracting only date and giving 0, and not considering time

Comment: Can anyone please help me to solve this

Comment: Hi @user12364618, Sorry for the late replay. You can not do math operations on results from `Highcharts.dateFormat` method because it is only a string. You should use milliseconds instead.